# scipy.stats.multivariate_normal generates samples but their cdf is zero

Tags: scipy, scipy.stats

I use scipy.stats.multivariate_normal to generate random samples of dimension (1, 9).

However, when i compute the cdf of said samples, it is always zero.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

mean = np.array([1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000,1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000])
std = np.array([35.98047,63.84033,49.01465,0.00000,59.04541,33.57812,59.36084,0.00000,11.00098])
normal = multivariate_normal(mean=mean, cov=np.diag(std**2),  allow_singular=True)
x_samples = []
cdf = []
for i in range(30):
    x_samples.append(normal.rvs())
for x_i in x_samples:
    cdf.append(normal.cdf(x_i))
print(cdf)
```

This prints [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

When I do the same thing but with dimesion (1,2) by changing third and fourth lines with:

```
mean = np.array([-1, 1])
std = np.array([150.98, 10.76])
```

It prints a non zero list with min = 0.001 and max = 0.933

I tried to re-iterate this random generation of (1,9)-dimension samples multiple times but the cdf of the samples is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

SciPy is misbehaving here. You can get it to do better by specifying a `lower_limit` (lower limit of integration) that is sufficiently far from the center but not infinite.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

rng = np.random.default_rng(8425833545683)
mean = np.array([1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000,1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000])
std = np.array([35.98047,63.84033,49.01465,0.00000,59.04541,33.57812,59.36084,0.00000,11.00098])
normal = multivariate_normal(mean=mean, cov=np.diag(std**2), allow_singular=True)
x = normal.rvs(size=4, random_state=rng)
cdf = normal.cdf(x, lower_limit=mean-10*std) # or 100*std, etc.
cdf  # array([1.21927224e-02, 9.15572026e-02, 1.96848083e-05, 7.67669868e-04])
```

The inspiration here was that sometimes using reasonable, finite limits of integration helps the integrator find the interesting portion of an integrand that is almost zero everywhere except for a small portion. (I'm not sure that is actually what is helping here, though.)

The results agree with what you get when you drop into the lower-dimensional subspace implied by the covariance matrix.

```py
i = (std != 0)
mean2 = mean[i]
std2 = std[i]
normal2 = multivariate_normal(mean=mean2, cov=np.diag(std2**2))
cdf2 = normal2.cdf(x[:, i])
cdf2  # array([1.21927224e-02, 9.15572026e-02, 1.96848083e-05, 7.67669868e-04])
```